# call api by retrofit2 and rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

Retrofit interface:
    @GET("search")
    Observable< ArrayList< Word>> Search();

```
Retrofit retrofit = retrofitclient.getInstance();
    API = retrofit.create(NODEjs.class);
compositeDisposable.add(API.Search()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<ArrayList<Word>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(ArrayList<Word> words) throws Exception {
            wordList.addAll(words);
        }
    }));
```

gradle:

```
//Rxjava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.loginlogout/com.example.loginlogout.vocabulary.vocabulary_activity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for
>   java.util.ArrayList

Please help me!!

Comment: You are using a scaler converter. You are expecting a ArrayList<Words>. You need to change to Observable<List<Words>> and use rxjava convertor

Comment: And please post how you are initializing Retrofit?

Comment: Retrofit retrofit = retrofitclient.getInstance();
        API = retrofit.create(NODEjs.class);

Comment: I have changed, but: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example.loginlogout.vocabulary.Word>

Comment: can you paste your full error log and the class where you are getting the error.